# unable to install WiFi driver in Kali linux, bc not found

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

I am having problem with installing Wi-Fi drivers for my laptop, which is a HP pavilion 15-eg1848nd, while installing kali Linux it fails to detect the built in Wi-Fi card.

I tried downloading manually from github and transferring the drivers on my laptop but it still does not work, whenever I try to run make or make install I get the following error:

`bin/sh:1 bc not found, makefile:2454: modules error2`

I also do not have dkms installed on this kali Linux and I do not know what to do.
I tried to use a USB Wi-Fi dongle to get the Wi-Fi working but still no solution.

I would really appreciate any ideas to help me.

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Try here:   https://www.wirelesshack.org/best-kali-linux-compatible-usb-adapter-dongles.html   for another adapter but with Kali Drivers.

Comment: Nothing helps, is there a chance to be a hardware problem ? I just tried installing parrot os and it seems to have the same problem, but with windows it is working fine. I do not understand where is the issue..

Answer (score 0):

The error `bc not found` should contain all necessary information to solve the problem.

Usually a package cannot be found if it is not installed.

The solution in this case would be to install `bc`.

As kali is based on debian, you can use `apt` to do so:

`sudo apt install bc`

Comment: But this requires another network connection(wired). What if we do  not have that? How do we install files. Are there binaries available elsewhere?

Comment: @vidyarthi This is not in scope of this question. Also there are [mul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919114/run-sudo-apt-get-install-without-internet-connection)[ti](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930429/get-installed-packages-url-using-apt)[ple](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/b/bc/) solutions depending on your preference.